# gradle-aspectj: Weaving & ajc compiler options working in compile but not in test task

Tags: spring, gradle, aspectj, build.gradle, ajdt

I have set up weaving successfully in Eclipse via the [AJDT](https://eclipse.org/ajdt/) plugin and in my gradle build via the [gradle-aspectj](https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj) plugin (which took quite some time...).

In Eclipse this works both for production and test code, i.e. all tests pass.
When I run the gradle build, the resulting app also works fine and I can see that aspects are working as expected.

The gradle "test" task however fails as many tests fail. I can track most of the failures back to some aspect (here: for spring transactions) not working or some ajc-compiler option for encoding not being active (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34445077/2574340) for details). The same tests do run fine when triggered from Eclipse.

Is some additional configuration required in order to get the weaving to work for tests as well?

I found some related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29487317/2574340), however this didn't resolve the issue for me. It still looks like neither aspects are picked up, nor compiler options are active (I see encoding errors in tests only).

My (abbreviated) build.gradle (Note: I had a hard time getting weaving to work at all so this probably contains some unnecessary configuration):

```
buildscript
{
  dependencies
  {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.6.RELEASE")
    classpath("nl.eveoh:gradle-aspectj:1.6")
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'aspectj'

configurations {
  runtime
  testCompile {
    extendsFrom testAspectpath
  }
  aspectpath
  testAspectpath
  ajInpath
  compile {
    extendsFrom aspectpath
  }
}

dependencies
{
  // Non aspect dependencies
  // ...

  // Dependencies that require weaving - works for compile but not for test task
  aspectpath("org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.1.RELEASE")
  compile("org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.1.RELEASE")
  aspectpath("org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.2.1.RELEASE")
  compile("org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.2.1.RELEASE")
  compile 'com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter:1.0.0'
  testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springVersion}")

  // Spring Data Neo4j
  compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:${springDataGraphVersion}"

  // Additional aspects - also need to be configured in ADJT
  aspectpath "org.aspectj:aspectjtools:${aspectjVersion}"
  compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:${aspectjVersion}"
  testCompile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:${aspectjVersion}"
  compile "org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.2.1.RELEASE"
  aspectpath "org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.2.1.RELEASE"
  compile "org.springframework:spring-instrument:3.2.1.RELEASE"
  aspectpath "org.springframework:spring-instrument:3.2.1.RELEASE"
  compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-aspects:${springDataGraphVersion}"
  aspectpath "org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-aspects:${springDataGraphVersion}"
  // Required by spring aspects
  compile "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final"
  aspectpath "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final"
  compile "javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0"
  aspectpath "javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0"
  testAspectpath sourceSets.main.output // from related question [4]
}

compileAspect {
  // Works in compile but not in test task!
  additionalAjcArgs = ['encoding' : 'UTF-8']
}
```

Edit: Encoding problem has been solved with snippet from kriegaex.
The problem of aspects that are not present in tests when run from gradle still remains.
Most tests fail because of a

> org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException

which indicates that the method based annotation

> @Transactional

is not effective.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried but according to the [plugin description](https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj) I think you should add this to your Gradle config file:

```
compileTestAspect {
  additionalAjcArgs = ['encoding' : 'UTF-8']
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps for the encoding problem! The problem with missing aspects in tests still remains (see updated question) though.